# Difference between these two mysql queries

Tags: mysql, sql

I want to know the difference between these two queries: The first query is giving me all the records and its just fine.

```
 Select * from table1 where tender_id='$tender_id' group by supplier_name
```

But in the following query I have added a sum(case), but I am not getting the desired output. The first query is showing all the records, but the second query is not showing all the records. What mistake am I making?

```
select cs.*, tender_id, 
SUM(CASE WHEN ifmain = 'Yes' THEN total_inr ELSE 0 END) AS maintotal, 
SUM(CASE WHEN ifmain = 'No' THEN total_inr ELSE 0 END) AS subtotal  
from table1 cs 
where cs.tender_id='$tender_id' 
group by cs.supplier_name
```

I want to know if the second query can display all the records with conditions (tender_id)? or its iterating more?

Comment: first off `select *` can cause some problems. why do you need it

Comment: The second SQL query, an alias is being used for the table name `table1`. So some columns are being prefixed with the table alias and some are not, an alias is really only needed for joins when there is the potential for similar column names in different tables.

Comment: Yes i understand that. There are lots of fields in that table, so in the real environment i have put all the fields. here just to show i have put (*)

Comment: Without alias is there a way i can get the maintotal and subtotal?

Comment: The first is not just fine!!!!!!!!!

Comment: its fine, but in that i need to add the sum(case) to find maintotal and subtotal. The second query is after inserting the case statement. But iam not getting the desired output like the first query.

Comment: Unless supplier_name is unique on that table neither query should return all the rows. The first query will return one row for each supplier_name, but which row the data is taken from for each supplier_name is not defined.

Comment: when working with group by try showing only the fields you really require

Answer (score 0):

> In standard SQL, a query that includes a GROUP BY clause cannot refer
>   to nonaggregated columns in the select list that are not named in the
>   GROUP BY clause.
>   see (for example) https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-handling.html

MySQL has a an unfortunate (and in my opinion incorrect) default behavior when using a GROUP BY clause. This query would NOT be valid in most SQL databases:

```
Select * from table1 where tender_id='$tender_id' group by supplier_name
```

and it would not be valid in MySQL either if the ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY SQL mode has been enabled.

I strongly recommend you treat all queries using GROUP BY as needing ALL non-aggregating columns in that clause. e.g.

```
select
    cs.supplier_name
  , SUM(CASE WHEN ifmain = 'Yes' THEN total_inr ELSE 0 END) AS maintotal
  , SUM(CASE WHEN ifmain = 'No' THEN total_inr ELSE 0 END) AS subtotal  
from table1 cs 
where cs.tender_id='$tender_id' 
group by
    cs.supplier_name
```

If you need extra columns then e.g.

```
select
    cs.supplier_name
  , tender_id
  , SUM(CASE WHEN ifmain = 'Yes' THEN total_inr ELSE 0 END) AS maintotal
  , SUM(CASE WHEN ifmain = 'No' THEN total_inr ELSE 0 END) AS subtotal  
from table1 cs 
where cs.tender_id='$tender_id' 
group by
    cs.supplier_name
  , tender_id
```

and so on. Of course as you include more columns in the group by clause you may increase the number of rows produced, but that is how GROUP BY should work.